# How to add on comment's field in views

Tags: views, comments

In Drupal 7, I've added a field from comment field section *(under manage field)* of a content type.
Now I want to add this field in a views.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "manage display" after the tab of "manage field" and set label and format and drag out from hidden that it. If you are talking about views under field section you can click on add and search for the field you definitely find there.